# Telethon timeout for resending message

Tags: python, telethon

I want to send a message to a telegram bot using `Telethon` and handle its response using an event handler function. Is there a way to set a timeout for the incoming event? For example, If I send "Hi" message to the bot and it doesn't respond to me after 5 seconds, Telethon send the "Hi" message again.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to create a handler and bind in on `NewMessage` event of our telethon client.

```
from datetime import datetime
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser

client = TelegramClient('session_name', app_id, 'app_token')
last_message_received_on = None


@client.on(events.NewMessage)
def on_message_received(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    print(event.raw_text)
```

Now in our `on_message_received` handler we need to add a line to determine on what `datetime` the bot has responded to us. So we change the handler to:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
def on_message_received(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    global last_message_received_on
    last_message_received_on = datetime.now()
```

Now we start the client and run a loop. We send the bot a message and check to see if we receive the response in less than five seconds. We continue this loop until the response is received under 5 seconds. I guess you get the gist now.

```
with client.start():
    bot = client.get_entity('https://t.me/some_user_name')

    while True:
        send_message('hi')
        if not last_message_received_on or (last_message_received_on < datetime.now()).seconds > 5:
            send_message('hi')
        else:
            break
```

Also you need to `time.sleep()` between sending your message again for at least 1 second to make the things natural and realistic. cause you don't expect the not to response instantly!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this the only way? Is there a way that Telethon do it for us automatically?

Comment: @SaraFahim I don't think so. It's fairly easy to implement though.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's the easiest way. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you test your code? It's an infinite loop even using time.sleep().

Comment: @SaraFahim it is not supposed to be a complete snippet. I just wanted you to get the jist.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you :(